# How to packetize AMR data in a RTP packet

Tags: rtp, amr

I am reading AMR payload from amr file, and then sending the same in RTP packet.
In amr file, after file header, frame header + speech frames are present.
The frame header portion in file looks as below.

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |P|  FT   |Q|P|P|
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Where FT is speech coding mode and Q bit says about frame quality.

Now when I packetize AMR data in a RTP packet, the header before speech frame contains

CMR as below

```
    0 1 2 3
   +-+-+-+-+
   |  CMR  |
   +-+-+-+-+
```

And ToC as below

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |F|  FT   |Q|
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

In ToC the F bit indicates if speech frame is last one in packet or not.
If F bit is 1, then there is a next speech frame in packet.
If F bit is 0, then there is no speech frame present in packet.

From amr file, I do not have any data that indicates what value F bit should have.
How do I know whether I need to set F bit to 0 or 1?